# Display Version, container name, timestamp in Kibana with EFK

Tags: php, elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd, efk

I have a PHP app deployed with Dockerfile, using EFK stack (Elasticsearch, Fluent-d, and Kibana) and I'm using "Logger\FluentLogger"
plugin to send the log to the elasticsearch.

`$logger = new FluentLogger(FLUENTD_ENDPOINT, FLUENTD_PORT);
$logger -> post("c", array("message"=>"executed query: ..."));`

When I build the docker image I export two variables :

`RUN export SERVICE_VERSION=$(head -n 1 .version) && export BUILD_TIMESTAMP=$(head -2 .version | tail -1)`

I want to write these two variable with every logging operation. I want also to display the container name like this:
[output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ae6r.png)

Comment: Are you after [getting the env vars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) or passing it to the logger?

Comment: passing it to the logger